# Replace part of a vector with a part of another vector of the same data.frame

Tags: r, vector, replace, dataframe, character

i want to replace rows 4 to 6 of article.y with row 4 to 6 of article.x
i'm sure there's a very simple solution, but i just haven't managed to find it.
my data.frame

```
no <- c(1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5)
article.y <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")
article.x <- c("apple", "peach", "plum", "berry", "cherry", "banana")

mydf <- data.frame(no, article.y, article.x)
mydf

#  no article.y article.x
# 1 1       one     apple
# 2 4       two     peach
# 3 6     three      plum
# 4 3      four     berry
# 5 2      five    cherry
# 6 5       six    banana
```

the output should look like this:

```
#   no article.y article.x 
#  1 1       one     apple
#  2 4       two     peach
#  3 6     three      plum
#  4 3     berry     berry
#  5 2    cherry    cherry
#  6 5    banana    banana
```

one of my desperate approaches:

```
mydf$article.y[4:6] <- mydf$article.x[4:6]
```

Comment: If you create your `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` it should work: `mydf <- data.frame(no, article.y, article.x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're just running into problems because you are working with factors. Convert the relevant columns to `character` first, and then you can use your approach or similar variants:

```
mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], as.character)
mydf[4:6, 2] <- mydf[4:6, 3]
mydf
#   no article.y article.x
# 1  1       one     apple
# 2  4       two     peach
# 3  6     three      plum
# 4  3     berry     berry
# 5  2    cherry    cherry
# 6  5    banana    banana
```